# No type hint with return values for TypedDict in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, python-typing

Atm I am starting with the `typing` library. When I create a wrong dict in-line I will get a typehint that the created dictionary is indeed not correct, and **'type hint': 42** is highlighted.

Is it normal that the wrong return value in the function is not highlighted? Which is **'no type hint': 88** in this case.

```
from typing import TypedDict

class Test(TypedDict):
    asdf: str
    a1: int

asdf: Test = {'type hint': 42}

def raw_to_prop() -> Test:
    return {'no type hint': 88}
```

Comment: I get 2 type hints on both dictionary creations (in the main body and in `raw_to_prop`), as you'd expect because both are missing the keys you defined and both introduce an unknown key. I'm using an up to date PyCharm, and Python 3.10 on Windows. I can either not reproduce your problem, or the explanation is not clear to me - what is the problem? If you're not getting both type hints, is your PyCharm, Python, and rest of your environment up to date? What else do you have installed that could affect type hinting? Are your PyCharm settings default?

Comment: Okay, thanks for checking. The typehints do work for the standard types. It is the first time I am using a custom typehint, and I did expect the same result as yours, but that didn't happen. So going to check for an update now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this question should end up getting closed, but here's what I see in PyCharm 2022.2.3 with a Python 3.10 environment on Windows 10:

[image]

And:

[image]

Note that the squigly lines are the result of there not being sufficient empty lines between the function definitions and the rest of the main body code.